# Distinct is not working with IEquatable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, distinct, gethashcode, iequatable

I have a class Bar that looks like this:

```
public class Bar : IEquatable<Bar>
{
    public string Stringbar1{ get; set; }
    public string Stringbar2{ get; set; }
    public string Stringbar3{ get; set; }
    public string Stringbar4{ get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public EnumFoo1 Enumfoo1{ get; set; }

    public bool IsBar{ get; set; }
    public List<string> StringBars{ get; set; }
    [BsonSerializer(SerializerType = typeof(NullableDateTimeOffsetToUtcSerializer))]
    public DateTimeOffset? FooDate{ get; set; }
    public string Stringbar5{ get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public EnumFoo2 EnumFoo2 { get; set; }
    public string StringBar6{ get; set; }
    public int Foo{ get; set; }
 
    public Bar()
    {
        EnumFoo1= EnumFoo1.Unknown;
        EnumFoo2= EnumFoo2.Other;
        StringBars= new List<string>();
    }

 public bool Equals(Bar other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Stringbar1 == other.Stringbar1&& Stringbar2== other.Stringbar2 && Stringbar3== other.Stringbar3 && Stringbar4== other.Stringbar4 && EnumFoo1== other.EnumFoo1 && IsBar== other.IsBar&&  BothNullOrEquals(StringBars,other.StringBars) && StringBar5==other.StringBar5&& FooDate== other.FooDate && ContractType == other.ContractType && LotNumber == other.LotNumber && Rank == other.Rank;
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var stringbar1Hashcode = Stringbar1== null ? 0 : Stringbar1.GetHashCode();
        var stringbar2HashCode = Stringbar2== null ? 0 : Stringbar2.GetHashCode();
        var stringbar3CodeHashCode = Stringbar3== null ? 0 : Stringbar3.GetHashCode();
        var EnumFoo1HashCode =  EnumFoo1.GetHashCode();
        var Stringbar4HashCode = Stringbar4== null ? 0 : Stringbar4.GetHashCode();
        var isBarHashCode =  IsBar.GetHashCode();
        var strtingBarsHashCode = StringBars== null ? 0 : StringBars.GetHashCode();
        var stringbar5HashCode = Stringbar5== null ? 0 : Stringbar5.GetHashCode();
        var fooDateHashCode = FooDate== null ? 0 : FooDate.GetHashCode();
        var enumFoo2HashCode= EnumFoo2.GetHashCode();
         var stringBar6HasCode = StringBar6== null ? 0 : StringBar6.GetHashCode();
        var fooHashCode= Foo.GetHashCode();
        return stringbar1Hashcode ^ stringbar2HashCode ^ stringbar3CodeHashCode ^ EnumFoo1HashCode ^ Stringbar4HashCode ^ isBarHashCode ^ strtingBarsHashCode ^ stringbar5HashCode ^ fooDateHashCode ^ enumFoo2HashCode ^ stringBar6HasCode  ^ fooHashCode ;
    }
    
    
    public static bool BothNullOrEquals<T>(IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
    {
        if (left == null && right == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (left != null && right != null)
        {
            return left.SequenceEqual(right);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Equals is working as expected but it seems that I am missing something when it comes to GetHashCode cause extension methods like LINQ Distinct are not working as expected. and I know that Distinct uses the GetHashCode method to compare references so any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You've overridden `GetHashCode` but haven't overridden `Equals(Object)`. You're required to override both. I suspect it's that which is causing issues.

Comment: What issues do you see with e.g. LINQ Distinct? You say they're not working as expected, so what are your expectations and what do you get instead?

Comment: You're not actually required to override both. You're required to override `GetHashCode` *if* you override `Equals(Object)`, but not the other way around.

Comment: @madreflection - you may say that but the [documentation says otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-7.0#notes-to-inheritors): "Derived classes that override GetHashCode() must also override Equals(Object)". The justification given there does sound a bit garbled but that's what it says.

Comment: It says that overriding `Equals(Object)` is to guarantee that they have the same hash code, but that's not what overriding `Equals(Object)` does. The statement you're quoting is incorrect.

Comment: StringBars.GetHashCode() looks like a bad idea; that could be anything and doesn't match your definition of equality - maybe just skip that one? (along with a `public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Bar other && Equals(other);`)

Comment: And the documentation for `IEquatable` also says that you *should* override both.

Comment: *"should"* - That's fine. I agree with that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `public override int GetHashCode() => 0;` is a perfectly valid implementation, if only just to make sure that everything else works. `GetHashCode` is notoriously difficult to implement in a way that gets a broad set of values (making false potential equality less of an issue), which is why the `HashCode` class was created. Using `HashCode.Combine` to generate a hash code is a much better way to implement it.

Comment: @madreflection Unfortunately the application is using .netstandard2.0 which does not support this, it was first presented in 2.1.

Comment: @MohamadHammash: Got you covered:  [Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I can see is in the

```
var strtingBarsHashCode = StringBars== null ? 0 : StringBars.GetHashCode();
```

Please, note that for `List<string> StringBars` HashCode is *reference based*:
hash codes are *guaranteed* to be equal if `StringBars` *share the same reference* only. However, you *compare* these collections by more *relaxing* scheme:

```
BothNullOrEquals(StringBars, other.StringBars)
```

So, `StringBars` doesn't have to share the same reference to be equal, they
should have *equal items only*. Note that `GetHashCode` must not return *different* codes for *equal* instances.

Don't make `GetHashCode` that elaborated; please, note, that `GetHashCode` should be a *fast* estimation of `Equals`; to be so `2 .. 3` *selective* properties are enough:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
  // Let .Net check for null and combine hash codes for you
  return HashCode.Combine(Stringbar1, Stringbar2, Stringbar3);
}
```

**Edit:** If you can't use `HashCode.Combine`, well let it be `^`, but, please, don't put many fields and properties into `GetHashCode` just a few the most selective ones:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
  // Let .Net check for null and combine hash codes for you
  return (Stringbar1?.GetHashCode() ?? 0) ^
         (Stringbar2?.GetHashCode() ?? 0) ^
         (Stringbar3?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the application is using .netstandard2.0 which does not support this.